# Padding-width and vertical spacing in Bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**First question:**

The textbox around `<h1>Get in contact</h1>` ignores padding-specifications for the width. This results in a textbox over the fully width of `col-md-6` which is far to big. I prefer to bring it down to about `50px`. The padding-specifications for the height are accurate. How can I let padding-width listen to me?

**Answer to the First question**: the problem is the height here `.jumbo .col .drie {height: 350px;}`. Simply remove `height: 350px`. Thanks to *SheHary*!

**Second question:**

This same `<h1>Get in contact</h1>`-text is placed underneath the `id="drie"`-image. This `h1`-text vertically spacing commands are not listening either. For example `vertical-align: bottom` is not working. But `text-align: center` brings the text to the middle/center. How to lower this text in the column, away of the `id="drie"`-image?

**Code:**

```css
.jumbo .col .drie {
    height: 350px;
    margin: 25px;
}

.jumbo .col .drie img {
    height: 120px;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
}

.jumbo .col .drie h1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 15px 50px;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    border-radius: 1500px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1.1px;

}
```

```html
<div class="jumbo">
<div class="container">
<div class="col">
   <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="drie">
         
          <img id="drie" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/broadway/design.svg" class="img-responsive center-block">
         
           <div class="driedrie" style="display:none">
              <h1>Get in contact</h1>
           </div>
              
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the problem is the height here `.jumbo .col .drie {height: 350px;}` after removing height http://jsfiddle.net/b09ap0kj/

Comment: give margin-top to `h1` and push it down as far you like http://jsfiddle.net/b09ap0kj/1/